# Can't center content in a column

Tags: html, css

I have a box with two parts - an information panel and a pic. I'm trying to get two of these boxes in the same row, centered in their respective column.

I've tried all the solutions I've found on this site. `Center-block`, `align="center"`, `margin: auto`, `float` and plenty others. I cannot figure this out.

Anytime I try to apply some sort of centering class, it moves the pic a little bit and nothing else.

Here's the code. I tried adding a class to the divs that have comments saying first and second box. I've since removed it since it had no effect.

```css
.box-sm {
  background-color: #e0dbc8;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.box-sm-pic {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- First Box -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 box-sm">
          <!-- Header, Description and button -->
          <h2>ROOMS</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur maiores eum quod repudiandae, voluptates recusandae?</p>
          <br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block">BOOK NOW</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 box-sm-pic">
          <!-- Image -->
          <img src="img/box-rooms.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="300" height="300" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- Second Box -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 box-sm">
          <!-- Header, Description and button -->
          <h2>ROOMS</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur maiores eum quod repudiandae, voluptates recusandae?</p>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block">BOOK NOW</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 box-sm-pic">
          <!-- Image -->
          <img src="img/box-rooms.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="300" height="300" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The boxes appear correctly but are left aligned. Someone please help!

Comment: Doesn't work. I added it to the line with the comments saying first and second box. It moved the whole thing over about 4px or so and that's it.

Comment: So, you want the boxes to be in a single row or you want then text in them center aligned?

Comment: The text in them is already center aligned with other css. I want the boxes to be centered in their respective columns:

OOXXOOXXOO <----Like this.

XXOOOXXOOO <----This is what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.box-sm {
    background-color: #e0dbc8;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.box-sm-pic {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.column {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <!-- First Box -->
            <div class="column">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box-sm">
                    <!-- Header, Description and button -->
                    <h2>ROOMS</h2>
                    <br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur maiores eum quod repudiandae, voluptates recusandae?</p>
                    <br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block">BOOK NOW</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box-sm-pic">
                    <!-- Image -->
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-responsive" width="300" height="300" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <!-- Second Box -->
            <div class="column">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box-sm">
                    <!-- Header, Description and button -->
                    <h2>ROOMS</h2>
                    <br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur maiores eum quod repudiandae, voluptates recusandae?</p>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block">BOOK NOW</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box-sm-pic">
                    <!-- Image -->
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-responsive" width="300" height="300" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This had no effect.

Comment: I have updated the code, and it should work now. please take a look.

Comment: Wow, that really reworked it! The content is now centered within it's column exactly how I want! The design doesn't quite collapse into mobile how I'd like it to but I believe I can work that part out. Thank you so much!

Comment: The reason it doesnt, and I thought about working all of that, but since it wasn't part of the full requirements, I didn't want to mess with code that may have been there on purpose. But you have padding being called into different areas. If you inspect element you should be able to find which classes are calling in the padding and set the padding to 0 on those classes.

Answer (score 0):

The width and margin attributes you are setting are overiding bootstraps. I think this is what you are looking for.

- Removed your classes ".box-sm" and ".box-sm-pic"
- Added CDN for bootstrap for my local dev (I know this is bad formatting)

Feel free to edit from here. I hope this helps.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- First Box -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <!-- Header, Description and button -->
          <h2>ROOMS</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur maiores eum quod repudiandae, voluptates recusandae?</p>
          <br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block">BOOK NOW</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <!-- Image -->
          <img src=" http://fillmurray.com/300/300" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- Second Box -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <!-- Header, Description and button -->
          <h2>ROOMS</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur maiores eum quod repudiandae, voluptates recusandae?</p>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block">BOOK NOW</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 box-sm-pic">
          <!-- Image -->
          <img src=" http://fillmurray.com/300/300" class="img-responsive"  alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What am I missing? All I see is a reference to a new Bootstrap document?

Comment: I removed the container-fluid class to put them in a more standard row. If you want you can leave that as is. Also, if you read the bullets above the code you'll notice I removed the classes you had in your code as the attributes you had were overriding bootstraps. Here's a codepen for referance:https://codepen.io/adamdoe/pen/eeEWZG

Note: I removed the link in the codepen and used codepens bootstrap include. My apologies if this wasnt what you were going for.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `style="text-align: center"` at the first row class. Please comment down if this is not what you are expecting.

```css
.box-sm {
  background-color: #e0dbc8;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

.box-sm-pic {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- First Box -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 box-sm">
          <!-- Header, Description and button -->
          <h2>ROOMS</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur maiores eum quod repudiandae, voluptates recusandae?</p>
          <br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block">BOOK NOW</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 box-sm-pic">
          <!-- Image -->
          <img src="img/box-rooms.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="300" height="300" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- Second Box -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 box-sm">
          <!-- Header, Description and button -->
          <h2>ROOMS</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur maiores eum quod repudiandae, voluptates recusandae?</p>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block">BOOK NOW</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 box-sm-pic">
          <!-- Image -->
          <img src="img/box-rooms.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="300" height="300" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No effect. This was one of the first methods I tried.

Comment: Check it out now.

Comment: Made the changes you implemented and absolutely nothing happened. There has to be something I'm missing, some bootstrap element restricting it. I'll just have to look at it with fresh eyes tomorrow.

Comment: Is the output being shown in the console is that you are expecting? If so there is no reason why it would not work on your system.

Comment: The console is not showing what I'm looking for. It shows the two blocks in the center of the screen, above each other. And when implementing your changes to my code, the same did not occur.

Comment: I just added padding-left: 10%; to give the illusion it's out there. It's the best I can come up with for now.

Answer (score 0):

Make a div with class name centerblock. And add your html codes in that div.
And use this css.

```
   .centerblock {
         position: absolute;
         left: 50%;
         top: 50%;   /*  <<< here you can set the value you want  */
         transform: translate ( -50%, -50%)
      }
```

Comment: I tried this and it put my boxes up and above the slideshow, in the center of the screen, not the center of their respective columns.

Comment: I tried removing the top attribute and adjusting the left as well as the translate attributes and it just floated around too much. It didn't adjust correctly when resizing the window, either.

Answer (score 0):

if you can center a something with align or anything maybe the style crush with another style 
but you can still center your item with this `<center>your item</center>`

Comment: are you sure ? take <div class="col-lg-6 box-sm"></div> in this tag <center>take this</center>

Comment: Lol, yes I'm sure I know how to wrap something in a tag.